# JMSQueueAppender logback throwing error

Tags: java, apache, jms, slf4j, logback

I implemented logback using JMS Queue Appender. I am getting the following error on console:

```
SLF4J: The following loggers will not work because they were created
SLF4J: during the default configuration phase of the underlying logging system.
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportLoggerFactory
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportLoggerView
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.transport.FutureResponse
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor
SLF4J: org.apache.activemq.management.JMSEndpointStatsImpl
```

And following message inside the queue message:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEventVO
```

Please help